# Passing the address of a vector to constructor of a class to use within the class

Tags: c++, qt, vector, constructor

I am trying to append the processed data from a class's member function to a vector by passing the address to the class's constructor during dynamic allocation. In order to append the data to the vector passed in the constructor; a pointer to vector member takes the address of the constructor's argument. Then this class member is used to append the data. But this technique makes the program crash in Qt. Any help is appreciated.

```
void MainWindow::on_goButton_clicked()
{
    //This part of the code is removed for clarity
    QVector<QByteArray> readDataVec;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        //DataExtractor object is dynamically allocated and the address of avector is passed 
        DataExtractor *newDataExtractor = new DataExtractor(&readDataVec);
        newDataExtractor->setupURL(testAPI);
        newDataExtractor->extract();
    }
}
```

Constructor of DataExtractor

```
DataExtractor::DataExtractor(QVector<QByteArray> *vec)
{
    this->dataVec = vec; //dataVec is of type QVector<QByteArray>* member of the class
    qDebug() << "Constructor successful";

}

void DataExtractor::readData()
{
    this->readDataByteArray = this->reply->readAll();
    this->dataVec->push_back(x); //The ptr is used to append the data to the vector
    this->~DataExtractor(); //Dynamically allocated object is deleted
}
```

The program crash at the function `void DataExtractor::readData()`. What is the reason? How do I solve this problem? Is there any better way to solve what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Where the `DataExtractor::readData()` is called? Maybe the vector you are construction `DataExtractor` is out of scope and already destructed as it is created on the stack.

Comment: Eww, a function that calls it's own destructor.  Why???

Comment: @lepsch Hey :) Yes you are correct. `QVector<QByteArray> readDataVec` goes out of scope because `void MainWindow::on_goButton_clicked()` is finished running before `DataExtractor::readData()` can do its job (asynchronous network request). Thanks mate :)

Comment: @NathanOliver This is because I can just `delete DataExtractor` because I don't know when it will finish its job (asynchronous network reply). So I call the class's destructor when the class has got a reply and stored the data.

Comment: `this->~DataExtractor();`  (assuming you're using it correctly) will lead to a memory leak, as this does not free the memory allocated by `new`.  `delete this;` would be better

Comment: @M.M Oh really? I though calling the deconstructor will deallocate memory. Thank you for your info, I didn't know that.  I thought to call the deconstructor and `delete` are same.

Comment: It's really annoying to see people down vote without any comments. This is a place to learn, not everyone is a pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @lepsch mentioned. `QVector<QByteArray> readDataVec` goes out of scope since its within the `for` loop block. So the solution is to have the `QVector<QByteArray> readDataVec` as a member of the class `MainWindow` and pass the address to the conbstructor of `DataExtractor`.